# Why does the connect sequence matter?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

When using `connect` from `react-redux`, if I do `mapDispatchToProps` before `mapStateToProps`, the component fails to render stating `dispatch is not a function`:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getData: () => {
      dispatch(getSomething())
    }
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
      somevalue: state.somevalue,
  }
}

export default connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps ) ( Comp );

//export default connect( mapDispatchToProps, mapStateToProps ) ( Comp ); THIS FAILS
```

Why does the sequence for `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` matter?

Comment: why does the right function passed matter ? oh really haha nice one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it state in [react-redux documentation for connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options), it waits for 4 different parameters.

If you change the order of parameters your functions will fire with wrong parameters and this will cause your functions to fail.

> ```
> connect([mapStateToProps], [mapDispatchToProps], [mergeProps], [options])
> ```
>
> Connects a React component to a Redux store. connect is a facade
>   around connectAdvanced, providing a convenient API for the most common
>   use cases.
>
> It does not modify the component class passed to it; instead, it
>   returns a new, connected component class for you to use.